# HP ProLiant DL380 Boot Issues

Tags: boot

I've tried researching intensely to find out why every time I try to boot my server, my monitor that I use to see what I'm doing to the server, seems to say "Out of Range".

I have Ubuntu installed and it was working fine until I messed something up. I've tried booting into every OS it has listed in the OS selection options, nothing helps.

What's wrong? (Or could be a solution)

Comment: Could you provide the specific model and generation of your server?

Comment: HP Proliant DL380 Generation 3

Comment: Have you tried another monitor?

Comment: Preferably a monitor that's newer than the server in question.

Answer (score 2):

The server you're describing is an [HP ProLiant DL380 G3](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04282946) from ~2003.

That means that you're working with a 12 year-old server, so there's ALWAYS potential for hardware failure with something of that vintage.

The positive side is that you have a Integrated Lights-Out (ILO) interface on that server. The ILO will allow you to control the machine and see the screen without needing a monitor. If you haven't already configured the ILO, I guess it'll be tricky without a monitor... but it's worth trying.

Have you tested with a different monitor?

Edit:

*Ubuntu doesn't belong on hardware sometimes*... You probably ran updates and need to change the video mode. Please [see this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153040/frequency-out-of-range-please-change-display-mode) for help on how to edit Grub to resolve this. [Also here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ubuntu%20out%20of%20range&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: I can get into the iLO configuration screen, however once the server says "attempting to boot from hard drive" that's when it says "out of range"

Comment: @LoganButler Please see my edit and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153040/frequency-out-of-range-please-change-display-mode).

Comment: your monitor probably says that when there's no video signal, e.g. when it's being initialized. Unfortunately modern monitors take a long time to sync with the video signal when it's available again, meaning you usually can't see the first couple of seconds of the boot process. I used to keep around an old dumb VGA monitor until BIOSes starting using non-standard VGA timings which couldn't be displayed by the old monitor.